# How to use the second overload of the .click handler?

Tags: jquery

Refering to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/#click-eventData-handler), how do I pass `eventData` to the event handler?  What is the syntax that is needed?

```
 .click([eventData], handler)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in similar fashion as it works in case of bind function. Mentioned in its release log and documentation of [bind](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)
https://api.jquery.com/bind/

```js
$("#test").click({
  temp: ["click", "on", "me"]
}, function(e) {
  $('#result').html(e.data.temp.join(','))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test">Run</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Base on the documentation, it says: An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler. Which means, the eventData is **anything** which is an **object**. So, for that here's an example:

```js
var someObject = {
  "var1" : "test",
  "var2": "test2"
};

$("#tryme").click(someObject, function (){
  
  console.log(someObject.var2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="tryme">Try me</button>
```

Comment: I like your answer also, but can you enlighten me on why `someObject` is in the scope of the anonymous function?  Thanks.